# I can't start Laravel Homestead on MacOS using VMWare (port collision)

Tags: vagrant, vmware, homestead

I tried to setup a new Laravel project this afternoon and I must have did something to my Homestead/Vagrant configuration that ruined it. I think the command I used was *vagrant reload {id}*.

Now when I try to start my machine, I get the following error:

```
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'vmware_fusion' provider...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: Verifying vmnet devices are healthy...
==> homestead-7: Preparing network adapters...
Vagrant found a port collision for the specified port and virtual machine.
While this port was marked to be auto-corrected, the ports in the
auto-correction range are all also used.

VM: homestead-7
Forwarded port: 80 => 8000
```

When I run *Vagrant global-status*, I get this:

```
id       name        provider      state       directory                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
410757f  homestead-7 vmware_fusion not running /Users/Me/Homestead
```

I can't run *vagrant reload 410757f* as I get the same error above, and I can't provision the machine because it needs to be running.

I'm confused as to whats happening here. There is a networking colission, but I don't have any other vagrant boxes. I currently have 4 other Windows VM's, but I made sure I shut down each machine.

I've even tried destroying and recreating the homestead box (no luck). Any ideas?

**Edit** To extend on this, I tried looking for the process using *sudo lsof -i :8000*

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
vmnet-nat 3943 root   42u  IPv4 0x70d4a03b6f2dddd      0t0  TCP *:irdmi (LISTEN)
```

I killed that using *sudo kill -9 3943* and ran *sudo lsof -i :8000* again, which gave me nothing, then running homestead up again gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to solve this by removing and reinstalling VMWare.

Based on my readings online, the issue seemed to be with a cached setting relating to a previous VM on Fusion. Rather than hunt down what that might have been, I thought it was easier to just delete everything and reinstall.

I followed the instructions [here](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1017838) and then downloaded and reinstalled it from the VMWare website.

I hope this helps someone in the future!